# wp_query no me hace caso y muestra lo que quiere de Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, sql, woocommerce, wordpress-plugin

Necesito ejecutar 3 consultas a wp_query en una misma página. La primera es de las entradas regulares. La segunda y tercera son con productos de categorías WooCommerce.

En la segunda consulta quiero mostrar la categoría ID=18 curso Curso y la ID=19 taller Taller. En la tercera consulta quiero mostrar la categoría ID=20 coaching Coaching.

El punto es que al hacer las consultas de Woocommerce, me muestra Todos los productos de Todas las categorías.

Ya he utilizado los siguiente códigos, y el resultado es el mismo:

```
$cursos_y_talleres = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'product-cat' => '18,-19',
    'showposts' => 4
));
```

Las variaciones que he intentado:

- 'cat' => array('18,19')
- 'cat' => array('curso,taller')
- 'cat' => array('Curso,Taller')
- 'product-cat' => array('18,19')
- 'product-cat' => array('curso,taller')
- 'product-cat' => array('Curso,Taller')
- 'product-category' => array('18,19')
- 'product-category' => array('curso,taller')
- 'product-category' => array('Curso,Taller')
- 'product-cat' => '19,19,-20'
- 'tax_query'  => array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'field'  => 'id', 'terms'  => '18' ), 'showposts' => 2 ));

Tras cada consulta utilizo *wp_reset_postdata();* antes de ejecutar la siguiente consulta.
Agradezco mucho todas sus aportaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo encontré por fin, así:

```
$cursos = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'showposts' => 3,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => 'curso',
                    )
                )
            )            
        );
```

La explicación sale de esta liga:
https://stackoverrun.com/es/q/5574939

¡Gracias!